# Is there an algorithm to determine if there exists a dominant map between two curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms, algebraic-curves

Suppose I am given two smooth projective curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ over a field $k$ I want to know if there is an algorithm to decide whether there exists a nonconstant (and thus dominant) map $f : C_1 \to C_2$.

To make this question more precise, suppose I am given an affine plane models $f_1(x, y) = 0$ and $f_2(x, y) = 0$ for some polynomials $f_1, f_2 \in k[x,y]$ birationally equivalent to the curves $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then is there an algorithm to determine when there exists a nonconstant map $f : C_1 \to C_2$ defined over $k$? Of course, it suffices to find a nonconstant rational map between these affine models so we may reduce the problem to asking if there exist two nonconstant polynomials $a(x,y), b(x,y) \in k[x,y]$ such that $f_2(a(x,y), b(x,y)) \in f_1(x,y) \cdot k[x,y]$.

From Riemann-Hurwitz we can easily bound the degree of a possible morphism $f : C_1 \to C_2$ so it suffices to find an algorithm to compute if there exist morphisms $f : C_1 \to C_2$ of a fixed degree $n$.

I am particularly interested in the case for morphisms of degree $2$ and $3$ and $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ for my own applications. However, I am interested also in the general case out of curiosity if this problem is decidable.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. If there is an (efficient) algorithm known I would be very appreciative if somebody could point me to it in the literature or to an implementation if one exists.

Comment: (1): You mean Hurwitz, not Hurewicz. They are different people. If you believe that this distinction is unimportant then ask yourself this: how soon do you want to be confused with another person? (2) The Tate conjecture (a theorem for several decades) says that two elliptic curves over a finite field are isogenous if their zeta functions are equal. However, this has, as far as I know, not been made effective.

Comment: Thank you. Edited with apologies to Poland.

Comment: Since you have the degree bound, this is a question about solvability of a polynomial system of equations. This general problem is decidable (in principle), and the algorithm is called "elimination theory". So the question can only be "how fast and effective this algorithm can be made for your specific problem".

Comment: You might find some of the results and references in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00125 useful

Comment: Morphisms between elliptic curves may have arbitrarily large degree. Otherwise, Magma has some functionality with subfields of function fields https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/452 but it doesn't seem to address your question directly (but you may check the references).

Comment: G. Möhlmann, Einbettungen globaler Funktionenkörper Diplomarbeit TU Berlin 2008

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko But the answer to Hilbert's 10th problem is not known e.g. for Q. Elimination theory will work only over algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault ah yes, I overlooked this important case. However, I am most interested in the case $g \ge 2$ for both curves. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch this reference looks very relevant, do you know if anyone has implemented this algorithm? Unfortunately, my German is quite poor...

Comment: @BenC There is something implemented in Magma, maybe just Hess's algorithm to test isomorphism. You should write to Hess.

Comment: @Francois Brunault: But I thought that the field $\overline{F}_q$ in the question IS algebraically closed, or did I misunderstand the notation?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes but he also asks for general k.